# Flutter font awesome text below icons

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using the font awesome icons in my flutter app and I am trying to place descriptive text below the icons. I was hoping there was a property in the IconButton class for this but dont see one. Here is my code:

```
Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                  child: IconButton(
                     icon: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.checkSquare,),
                     iconSize: 60.0,
                     color: const Color(0xFF0099a9),
                      onPressed: () { print("Pressed"); }
                  )

              ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered this problem few days ago and here is how I solved it:

```
Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      GestureDetector(
          child: Icon(
            FontAwesomeIcons.checkSquare,
            size: 60.0,
            color: const Color(0xFF0099a9),
          ),
          onTap: () {
            print("Pressed");
          }),
      Text("Some Text")
    ],
  ),
),
```

With this solution you have access to many more features.

There may be a cleaner solution but this one is perfectly suitable to make a clickable icon with a text below ;)

Have a nice day !